# Using Hyperledger QBFT suitable for public chains?

Tags: private-blockchain, evm, poa, besu, qbft

I am thing process of creating my own public EVM network, i found the best approach available would be using QBFT on HyperLedger Besu as it is Proof Of Authority and secure for production uses. But everytwhere i check it shows to use it for private network. I wanted to know if it would be good to run a public network with validators with QBFT on Besu and are there any issues with that implementation when running publically instead of privately?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's confusing, but private network just means "not the ethereum mainnet".
Private means not everyone can validate blocks. But you can open it to anyone to read and send transactions.

You can create a private network that is publicly accessible, simply provide the IP or URL of your node to users with P2P endpoint as well as the genesis file config and they will be able to sync their own nodes.

If you want to be the only one to have nodes, provide the RPC endpoint.

This is how networks like Palm.io works. Is a private PoA network but anyone can use it.